# How to best convey excitement for the next assignment, quarter, or project?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, formality, business-language, correspondence

I’ve just received feedback on my work during the second quarter of the year (Q2) from my manager. I would like to reply to this feedback and end my reply with a sentence along the lines of"

> Looking forward to a ____ Q3!

In my native language, one could use our word corresponding to the English word *fruitful*.  But I don’t know whether *fruitful* would be ok to use in English, nor whether some better yet still professional way for expressing cheerful excitement about the next quarter exists.

I imagine I could also change the formula to something like:

> Looking forward to a Q3 full of ____.

or use a similar construction.

How can I convey my excitement about an upcoming assignment in a professional way?

Comment: English questions end in question marks. **There is no question here**, so this is Not A Real Question.  And even if there were, it would almost surely be either Primarily Opinion Based or else Too Broad.  Or if you are merely seeking a synonym for *fruitful*, then it is General Reference. In any event, you have shown no research.

Comment: [fruitful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fruitful). See sense 1.1.

Comment: Looking forward to an even better Q3? Don

Comment: Just **say** exactly what you are **thinking**.  Literally, what are you thinking?  Are you thinking "thanks for saying that" are you thinking "I know I can do even better" are you thinking "I'm very pleased with what happened".  Just state what you are thinking.

Answer (score 1):

In a business context, I would not say that "fruitful" is a bad choice, but it would not be my first one, since I personally consider it a little too general and bland. "Profitable" is usually an appropriate word to use for excitement in the next quarter in a business context, but I sometimes prepend "more", so

> Looking forward to a more profitable Q3!

"Challenging" (or, again, "more challenging") might be suitable if you anticipate a new task is anticipated. There are any number of terms that could be used, though, besides those I have suggested.